# Glide Picasso won't load thumbnail path of locally stored video

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, mediastore

I am trying to load all video files from `sdcard` in a recycler view. I also want the thumbnail of the video so here is my code to retrieve thumbnail of videos

```
var thumbColumns = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA)
fun getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(fileId:Long): String?{

        var thumbCursor: Cursor? = null
        try {

            thumbCursor = contentResolver.query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID + " = "
                    + fileId, null, null)

            if (thumbCursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA)),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                return thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA))
            }

        } finally {
            thumbCursor?.close()
        }

        return null
    }
```

The method returns the following path `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1526834275076.jpg`

Following are the ways in which I tried loading the image with glide

`video.thumbnailUrl` is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1526834275076.jpg`

1)

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(Uri.fromFile(File(video.thumbnailUrl)))
                .into(holder.thumbnail)
```

2)

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load("file:///"+video.thumbnailUrl)
                    .into(holder.thumbnail)
```

3)

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load("file://"+video.thumbnailUrl)
                    .into(holder.thumbnail)
```

4)

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                    .load(video.thumbnailUrl)))
                    .into(holder.thumbnail)
```

Same thing is done with `Picasso`. I even tried using Older version of `Glide` but still nothing. Most of the Stack Overflow questions mentions the first way but it is not working for me. I have tried from all Android Versions from 19 to 27 but couldn't load the image.

I am getting no such file or directory for all the cases but clearly the file is present otherwise I wouldn't get the path from `getThumbnailPathForLocalFile` function. I have added the read storage permission. Am I fetching the video thumbnails the right way?

Comment: i did not use this, some developer will tell you solution.

Comment: How about the read external storage permission in manifest? And runtime permision cods fir Android 6+?

Comment: @greenapps I have already done that. If I had not included the permission then how could I have got the path of the thumbnail. Problem is with Glide and Picasso

Comment: You got that path from the media store. To obtain that path you dont need permissions.

Comment: Start with http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html, you'll need to provide more detail on what specifically is failing

Comment: @greenapps of course I need permission to read the user's storage

Comment: @SamJudd I am getting no such file or directory for all the cases but clearly the file is present other wise I wouldn't get the path from getThumbnailPathForLocalFile function

Answer (score -1):

First use picasso latest gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Then you can simply do like this:

```
String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/myimg.png";
Picasso.get().load(new File(filePath)).into(imageView);
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: the app just crashed  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

Comment: So it's not your Picasson issue, you have issue with others. This code works for me, thanks.

Comment: do you understand that video and image are different things?

Comment: @user25 First read the question clearly. He return a thumbnail and try to show the thumbnail via Picasso.

Comment: @HasibAkter he tried to get thumbnail PATH and he did it wrong, there is no image